# Unable to parse the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to parse the date which is in the following format

```
dateFormat: "d-M-y" // returns 10-Oct-13
```

I'm using **`jQuery UI`** for formatting date.

Below is my code:

```
var d1 = new Date("10-Oct-13");
alert(d1);  //Invalid in FF and IE, works in chrome
```

[image]

Seems weird, here is my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mB6B7/2/) for reproducing the bug in FF and IE.

**Note:** I don't want to use plugin, since it is working chrome.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: this seems to do the trick: `dateFormat: "d/M/yy"`

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I don't want to change the date format.  However this didn't worked

Comment: @Jack I agree, but this is a common functionality, I wonder why there is no common rules among browser.

Comment: There is, Chrome has gone beyond it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MDN doc for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters):

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2Fparse) method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps).

Essentially you're passing a string in an unsupported date format as the `dateString` parameter of the constructor, so the JavaScript engine is (correctly) stating that it's an invalid date. Chrome seems to be slightly more forgiving with the date formats it allows, but that's non-standard.

You can use the [getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) function to obtain a Date object representing your selected date:

```
var d1 = $('#lastAssimilationDate').datepicker("getDate");
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info and workaround, wondering why it is taking time to apply common functionality among browser's JS engine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Datepicker's parseDate() method in conjunction with the format string to parse the date:

```
var d1 = $.datepicker.parseDate("d-M-y", $("#lastAssimilationDate").val())
alert(d1); // alerts: Thu Oct 10 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

See the [edited JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michalstanko/evXds/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`getDate` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate):

```
$('button').click(function(){    
    var d1 = $("#lastAssimilationDate" ).datepicker('getDate');
    console.log(d1);    
});
```

You can also assign an [`altField`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField) with an [`altFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altFormat) of `yyyy-mm-dd` if you need to send an ISO-standard date to the server.

Comment: +1 Tricky, thanks for letting me to know about altField and altFormat